# Sprinkles on rolled icing

Tags: icing

we are about to decorate some cup cakes and want to know the best way to put sprinkles onto rolled icing without the colours running or the sprinkles falling off They will be no. 3's and they will be placed on a stick to stand on the top of the cup cakes not laying flat on the top of the icing

Comment: Can you describe the "stick" a bit more, and how the sprinkles will be placed against it and the surface of the cupcake? A crude drawing in Paint could help a lot. I'm not quite understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Is the 'stick' going to be standing up?
if so you could dip it in melted chocolate and then into a bowl of sprinkles before leaving it to dry